# How to retrieve the JSON message body in JAX-RS REST method?

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs, put

I have the following `JSON` that will be passed as part of a HTTP request, in the message body.

```
{
    "names": [
        {
            "id":"<number>",
            "name":"<string>",
            "type":"<string>",
        }
    ]
}
```

My current `REST` handler is below. I am able to get the Id and `Version that is passed in as path params, but I am not sure how to retrieve the **contents on the message body**?

```
        @PUT
        @Path("/Id/{Id}/version/{version}/addPerson")
        public Response addPerson(@PathParam("Id") String Id,
                                                @PathParam("version") String version) {

            if (isNull(Id) || isEmpty(version)) {
                return ResponseBuilder.badRequest().build();
            }

            //HOW TO RECIEVE MESSAGE BODY?

            //carry out PUT request and return DTO: code not shown to keep example simple


            if (dto.isSuccess()) {
                return Response.ok().build();
            } else {
                return Response.serverError().build();
            }

}
```

Note: I am using the `JAX-RS` framework.

Comment: What web framework are you using?

Comment: Jax RS is the framework I am using

Comment: How have you done it for a POST request? 1) I think you need `@Consumes("application/json")` on your method, and you should be able to add an `@Context` parameter from which you can get the body and other information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to map your name json to a POJO and add @Consumes annotation to your put method, here is an example:

```
@PUT
@Consumes("application/json")
@Path("/Id/{Id}/version/{version}/addPerson")
public Response addPerson(@PathParam("Id") String Id,
                          @PathParam("version") String version,
                          List<NamObj> names) {
```

I assume you are trying to retrieve a list of elements if is not the case just use you POJO as it in the param.

Depending on what json library are you using in your server you may need to add @xml annotation to your POJO so the parser could know how to map the request, this is how the mapping for the example json should look like:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class NameObj {
   @XmlElement public int id;
   @XmlElement public String name;
   @XmlElement public String type;
}
```

Jersey doc: https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/user-guide.html#json

@cosumes reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gilik.html#gipyt

Comment: Ok, so I do not need the @Context annotation on the List within the parameters?

Comment: I don't think you need that, you don't need to access the context yourself jax-rs will retrieve the json object to your method and the json parser will map it to your list.

Comment: Yes, they work, I believe just jackson parser library has json specific annotations.