# Cant modify object iin Web API/Java Web App

Tags: java, rest, maven, tomcat, url

I am creating a Stock Management System Java Web Application with a REST web client. This system should allow users to add products, view products and modify the number of items in the database already. So far, I have successfully implemented the adding of items - using POST requests - and viewing them - using GET requests. However, I am having some difficulty modifying the quantity of each item. Here is the code for the Product class:

```
public class product {
    private int quantity;
    private String name;
    static AtomicInteger nextId = new AtomicInteger();
    private int id;
    public product(String name, int quantity) {
        this.name = name;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        id = nextId.incrementAndGet();
    }
```

The Java method for modifying the quantity of products:

```
public void addStock(String item, int stockLevel) {
    boolean found = checkExists(item)
    product product = getProduct(item);

    if(found == false) {
        a.setQuantity(stockLevel);
    }
    else {
    }
}
```

The `getProduct()` method iterates through the ArrayList that holds all products to retrieve the specific product I require, whilst `checkExists` checks if the product already exists in the database. If the item does not exist, I use the setQuantity method which is:

```
public void setQuantity(int amount) {
    this.quantity = quantity + amount;
}
```

What I want to do is if the user needs to increase the number of items available is to send a PUT request to change the number of items. So I tried this:

```
@PUT
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void addStock(String name, int amount) {
        itemService.addStock(name, amount);
    }
```

However, when I run this on the Tomcat server it runs into multiple errors. After some basic error checking, I figure out it is because of multiple parameters in the method addStock.

My question is, this method only works if I pass in a single parameter, either amount or name. However, I need both to change the amount of a specific item and I can't figure out how to do that with only being able to pass in a single parameter. Can someone help me out here? I have tried to implement an ID for each product which I would then use but I can't figure out how to do that either. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you encaplsulate your **addStock-modification(-data)** into a separate *data transfer object* (DTO)? So you could have:

```
public class StockChange {
  public String productName;
  public int amountChange;
}
```

Then you can add this DTO to your REST controller-method `addStock` as **body parameter** (in Spring add `@RequestBody` annotation). Of course the REST-client should then **PUT** following JSON:

```
{
  productName: 'my product', 
  amountChange: -125
}
```

Comment: If you are using **jax-rs** for handling REST then have a look at [How to retrieve the JSON message body in JAX-RS REST method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41041160/how-to-retrieve-the-json-message-body-in-jax-rs-rest-method#41041577) and maybe you benefit from the URL-design using _path-param_ as well :-)

Comment: Thank you, this looks like the type of thing I need, will try later on.